# Codeigniter can't find set_userdata() from model

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

The Session library is autoloaded

My model:

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function validate(){
        $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            $row = $query->row();
            $data = array(
                    'id' => $row->id,
                    'first_name' => $row->first_name,
                    'last_name' => $row->last_name,
                    'username' => $row->username,
                    'validated' => true
                    );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);    // ### line 28 ### 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Gives this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Session::set_userdata() in
>   /var/www/codeIgniterTest/_application/models/login_model.php on line
>   28

Comment: Make sure that you have added session library in config or current file.

Comment: What version of CI are you using? As of CI 3 (The current GitHub repo), the session is now a driver, not a library.

Answer (score 1):

Have you loaded the `Session` library?

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }
```

Comment: yes
autoload['libraries'] = array(
    'layout',
    'errors',
    'database',
    'session'
);

Comment: try loading it in `__construct()`, see if works that way.... debug, just like @pratiknagariya suggests. Do a `var_dump($this->session)`, if you get nothing, then the session library is not being loaded

Answer (score 1):

Try debugging and check all the included files by.

```
$included_files = get_included_files();

foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
    echo "$filename\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I created my own Session class, but forgot to extend the CI_Session.

Thanks for the help!